# Nancy access model state in view

Tags: c#, nancy, modelstate

Right now I am validating the model using nancy data annotations, but I'm not quite sure how to access the model state in the view (using Super Simple View Engine) if the model is not valid, for instance:

```
           Post("/register", async args =>
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.Query.returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProviders = _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();

            var model = this.BindAndValidate<RegisterViewModel>();

            if (ModelValidationResult.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var adminUsers = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("admin");
                    if (!adminUsers.Any())
                    {
                        if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("admin"))
                        {
                            var roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
                            {
                                Name = "admin",
                                NormalizedRoleName = "admin"
                            });

                            if (roleResult.Succeeded)
                            {
                                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "admin");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "admin");
                        }
                    }

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    Logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");

                    return Response.AsRedirect("~/");
                }
            }

            return View["register.html", model];
        });
```

If I return the user back to the register view after validating the model how can I access the errors there? It doesn't seem like there are any helper methods for outputting errors at the moment, but I figured there would be some sort of dictionary available to access the errors in the view. What exactly is the standard for outputting errors on a post back in Nancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass `ModelValidationResult` back to the view as well, instead of just the `model`.

Comment: I see, well I just changed it into an ajax request and sent the model validation result back that way...